# C++ have to handle the string key properly in a map

Tags: c++, c++11

In my **ClassA**, I have a class variable:

```
std::map<std::string, ClassB*> classBMap;
```

In one method, I initialize the map with values:

```
ClassA::init()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       string tempKey = "key" + to_string(i + 1);
       ClassB* b = new ClassB();
       classBMap.insert(make_pair(tempKey, b));
   }
}
```

In other methods, the **classBMap** is accessed by changing its ClassB* or deleting the entries with ClassB memory release.

My questions are related to the **string**, the **tempKey** key string.

**1.** The string key in the classBMap is a copy of the tempKey string?

**2.** should I do any thing special for the string key at the time I delete an entry from the classBMap? (I only delete the ClassB pointer after it is removed from the map now.)

**3.** Occasionally, I got the following error (all map access code are protected with **mutex**):

> error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7f94ffffffe7

in this access code: (**it->first**)

```
std::map<string, ClassB*>::iterator it = classBMap.begin();
while(it != classBMap.end())
{
    string idKey = it->first;
    ...
}
```

what are the possible causes for this error?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. You have a bug in your code, somewhere.

Comment: 1. It's a copy. 2. Removing the item from the `map` will `delete` the `pair` and the `string` will go with it. 3. This is to broad, the number of possible causes is staggering without a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you use a `std::string` as key? You actually convert an integer into the string... so why don't just use a simple `int` as key?

Comment: _"My questions"_ One question per question, please. This is a Q&A repository, not a discussion board.

Comment: Also note that with modern C++, you can get rid of all that manual error prone memory management (`std::unique_ptr` might be your friend), but do you need pointer semantics at all? Why not store `ClassB` directly in the map. That's an alternative worth considering if `ClassB` is not polymorphic (and you don't keep references to individual objects outside of this class).